# 404 after switching to https

Tags: https, 404-page, magento1.9.3

I have a Wildcard SSL certificate and yesterday I have asked to siteground to extend it to all my subdomains, the result is that today any https url throw the 404 error (except for index.php/homepage).

 Is it a problem of configuration or a bad installation of the certificate?

- I have tried to do not use the https and everything works fine
- I have just changed the config under System>General>Web>Secure and then cleaned up sessions, cache and memcache, restored file permission and reindexed the information, but with no luck.
  This is my .htaccess in my magento folder:

  ```
  #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
  #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

  DirectoryIndex index.php

  <IfModule mod_php5.c>

  php_value memory_limit 256M
  php_value max_execution_time 18000


  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off


  php_flag session.auto_start off


  #php_flag zlib.output_compression on


  php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off



  php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_security.c>


  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>


  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>


  SSLOptions StdEnvVars

  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>


  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on




  RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
  RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>

      Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

      BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s8 ie8
      Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block" env=!ie8

  </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

  </IfModule>

  AddDefaultCharset Off
  #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  <IfModule mod_expires.c>

  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

  </IfModule>

  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all


  <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
      order allow,deny
      deny from all
  </Files>

  #FileETag none


  <Files cron.php>


      #AuthName "Cron auth"
      #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
      #AuthType basic
      #Require valid-user

      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all

  </Files>
  ```

**EDIT**

- I'm using magento 1.9.3.1
- Admin area works fine

  **EDIT 2**
  Setting:
  [image: settings]

Comment: first tell us which magento version you are using?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Oops, sorry, I have just added it, it is 1.9.3.1

Comment: did you end up finding a solution @Razorphyn?  I'm testing out switching to full https, and am encountering the same issue.  Home page and admin works via https, but all other pages return 404.

Comment: @ZekeFarwell unfortunately not, I am not able to control those param, since I am on a shared hosting, I am just able to use the main domain in ssl, which the edit of .htaccess has solved, but the subdomain are not usable through ssl...

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same issue while testing out a switch to full https.  Home page and admin pages worked fine via https, but all other pages gave a 404.

In my case the root cause was an error in my Apache configuration.  Since Apache listens on a separate port for https:// (443 rather than 80) it also has a separate virtual host.  On my Ubuntu server the config files were at these paths:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf (port 80)
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf (port 443)
```

While the 000-default.conf file had an `AllowOverride All` declaration as shown below, this was missing from the default-ssl.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

After adding the directory node and `AllowOverride All` to the port 443 virtual host in default-ssl.conf, the 404 errors went away.  I believe the issue was that Magento relies on the .htaccess file for url rewrites to work on the front end, and Apache only parses .htaccess files when the `AllowOverride All` declaration is present.  Therefore url rewrites didn't work, thus the 404s.  Home page doesn't need a rewrite so it worked, and the admin doesn't use rewrites so it worked fine too.

Comment: Awesome! This is what I missed also (i.e. AllowOverride All) why SSL on my Magento 2 setup doesn't work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved:

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /shop/
```

It works for te main domain, but ot for the subdomain...